# Delphi - Compiler Directives multi lines effects selected IDE error line

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I'm wondering why if the compiler directives was typed on multi lines will effects the selected IDE error line.

For example:

```
{$SETPEFlAGS IMAGE_FILE_DEBUG_STRIPPED or
 IMAGE_FILE_LINE_NUMS_STRIPPED or
 IMAGE_FILE_LOCAL_SYMS_STRIPPED or
 IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED}

.....

procedure Foo();
begin
  WriteLn('1');
  WWriteLn('2');
  WriteLn('3');
  WriteLn('4');
  WriteLn('5');
end;
```

IDE Error

> [dcc32 Error] Crypter.dpr(29): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'WWriteLn'

Inside the source code the selected line is `WriteLn('5');` not `WWriteLn('2');`

But if the compiler directives was typed on this way (one line) :

```
{$SETPEFlAGS IMAGE_FILE_DEBUG_STRIPPED or IMAGE_FILE_LINE_NUMS_STRIPPED or IMAGE_FILE_LOCAL_SYMS_STRIPPED or IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED}
```

Will fix the issue!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If things are as you say, then this is a defect in the IDE. Report the issue as a bug to Quality Portal.

It's easy to work around the issue. Simply don't use multi-line directives. In this case you can extract the flag into a separate constant and refer to it in the directive.

```
const
  PEFlags = IMAGE_FILE_DEBUG_STRIPPED or
    IMAGE_FILE_LINE_NUMS_STRIPPED or
    IMAGE_FILE_LOCAL_SYMS_STRIPPED or
    IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED;

{$SETPEFlAGS PEFlags}
```

---

The reason I hesitate in the first paragraph is that what you describe would also occur if the linefeeds were incorrect. If your linefeeds are not CR+LF then the IDE gets confused about line numbers. So, it's worth checking that your linefeeds are CR+LF. You could simply re-type the code and the linefeeds will be correct. Typically you get mixed up linefeeds when you paste from another source.

Comment: I have also tried to re-type it but the issue still the same. So its a mainly bug. i will submitted to Quality Portal. Your code is the best work around looks nicer than the single line.